# Biopython Blast - AttributeError: 'Analyze' object has no attribute 'dbtype'

Tags: python, python-3.x, blast

I'm trying to analyze sequences using BLAST for python, and this was the original code I received. I was told at one point this code worked, but that it has since broken due to library updates.

I've tried looking for similar code to see if this was modified for something, but have had no such luck.

The error arises with the first line below, I've copied the whole definition to see if that will help. I've also been trying to figure it where it calls from with little success.

```
def blast(self):
    if self.dbtype == "nucl" and self.querytype=="nucl":
        self.blastn_cline = NCBIblast.NcbiblastnCommandline(query=self.outputfasta, db=self.format_filepath, outfmt=5, out=self.outputfasta + ".xml")
        stdout, stderr = self.blastn_cline()
    elif self.dbtype == "prot" and self.querytype=="nucl":
        self.blastx_cline = NCBIblast.NcbiblastxCommandline(query=self.outputfasta, db=self.format_filepath, outfmt=5, out=self.outputfasta + ".xml", seg='no')
        stdout, stderr = self.blastx_cline()
    elif self.dbtype == "nucl" and self.querytype=="prot":
        self.tblastn_cline = NCBIblast.NcbitblastnCommandline(query=self.outputfasta, db=self.format_filepath, outfmt=5, out=self.outputfasta + ".xml", seg='no')
        stdout, stderr = self.tblastn_cline()
    elif self.dbtype == "prot" and self.querytype=="prot":
        self.blastp_cline = NCBIblast.NcbiblastpCommandline(query=self.outputfasta, db=self.format_filepath, outfmt=5, out=self.outputfasta + ".xml", seg='no')
        stdout, stderr = self.blastp_cline()
    result_handle = open(self.outputfasta + ".xml")
    blast_records = NCBIXML.parse(result_handle)
    self.simpleresults = {}
    self.tophits = {}
    for record in blast_records:
        for hit in record.alignments:
            for hsp in hit.hsps:
                try:
                    self.simpleresults[record.query].append([hit.hit_id.strip(), hsp.identities, hsp.align_length, hsp.query.strip(), hsp.match, hsp.sbjct, hsp.query_start, hsp.sbjct_start, hsp.sbjct_end, hsp.query_end])

                except:
                    self.simpleresults[record.query]=[[hit.hit_id.strip(), hsp.identities, hsp.align_length, hsp.query.strip(), hsp.match, hsp.sbjct, hsp.query_start, hsp.sbjct_start, hsp.sbjct_end, hsp.query_end]]
            self.tophits[record.query]=self.simpleresults[record.query][0]
    x=0
    Label(self.result_frame, text="Query").grid(row=0, column = 1)
    Label(self.result_frame, text="Hit").grid(row=0, column=2)
    Label(self.result_frame, text="Percent ID").grid(row=0, column=3)
    Label(self.result_frame, text="Hit Coverage").grid(row=0, column=4)
    Label(self.result_frame, text="Ref Length").grid(row=0, column=5)
    for key in sorted(self.tophits.keys()):
        if int(100*self.tophits[key][1]/self.tophits[key][2])>=80:
            q=Text(self.result_frame, height=1, width=60)
            q.insert(1.0, key)
            q.grid(row=x+1, column=1)
            h=Text(self.result_frame, height=1, width=60)
            h.insert(1.0, self.tophits[key][0])
            h.grid(row=x+1, column=2)
            q.configure(relief=FLAT)
            h.configure(relief=FLAT)
            Label(self.result_frame, text=str(int(100*self.tophits[key][1]/self.tophits[key][2]))).grid(row=x+1, column=3)
            try:
                Label(self.result_frame, text=str(int(100*self.tophits[key][2]/len(self.refsequences[self.tophits[key][0]])))).grid(row=x+1, column=4)
            except:
                Label(self.result_frame, text=str(int(100*self.tophits[key][2]/len(self.tophits[key][5])))).grid(row=x+1, column=4)
            try:
                Label(self.result_frame, text=str(len(self.refsequences[self.tophits[key][0]]))).grid(row=x+1, column=5)
            except:
                Label(self.result_frame, text=str(len(self.tophits[key][5]))).grid(row=x+1, column=5)
            Button(self.result_frame, text="View alignment", command=lambda arg1=key : self.viewalignment(arg1)).grid(row=x+1, column=6)
            x+=1
    self.b3.destroy()
```

And the error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukec\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Code/2018-07-31_New/sequencetools.py", line 1183, in blast
    if self.dbtype == "nucl" and self.querytype=="nucl":
AttributeError: 'Analyze' object has no attribute 'dbtype'
```

Any solutions on how to get BLAST working again?

**Edit:** I've been able to find out that the dbtype works for a derivative of blast using console commands, but what would be the best way to port these over for the way my script is using them? See this: https://www.biostars.org/p/298929/